# Custom ArcGIS Server Web Service can't find Esri assemblies

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-web-adf

I have ArcGIS Server 10 installed on a server, with Web ADF Runtime and Web Applications installed, and I have a custom web service that uses a couple of ESRI.ArcGIS assemblies deployed on that server. When I run the web service, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=......" or one of
>   its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The web service uses .NET 3.5 and the ESRI assemblies are registered in the GAC. I also tried including them in a Bin folder in the app with no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You will want to make sure your are initializing your license properly as well; when working locally you get a pass; but when you publish to the server this can fail. This can cause the 'or one of its dependencies' error since the Init didn't fire.

Comment: Also make sure you set the Specific Version to false.

Comment: These are great suggestions, I'll give them a shot.

Comment: @D.E.Wright Your comment is the answer that fixed my issue. Can you please add it as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Done... Glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to make sure your are initializing your license properly as well; when working locally you get a pass; but when you publish to the server this can fail. This can cause the 'or one of its dependencies' error since the Init didn't fire.